# How to test Jersey simple via curl

Tags: curl, jersey-2.0

I had this simple class from Jersey tutorial. How can I make simple test just switch return type of format via curl? I don't want to write client.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    // This method is called if XML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

    // This method is called if HTML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>" + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>"
                + "</html> ";
    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend using Rest Console browser plugin instead of curl.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for XML:

```
curl -H "Accept: text/xml" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -X GET "http://localhost:8080/yourapp/hello"
```

And similar for text/html and text/plain